# Encode data extraction from an csv file

Tags: php, csv, extract

I have a CSV file that I want to extract data from :

```
$rapport_old = file_get_contents($dossier."\Rapport.csv");
$data_old = array_map("str_getcsv", preg_split('/\r*\n+|\r+/', $rapport_old));
```

This code does do the trick  but instead `Mot Clé` it change it to `Mot Cl�`how can I prevent that from happening?

 Much appreciated!

Comment: It doesn't change it, it's simply that you're not using the correct charset when you display it

Comment: Ya Mark Baker, Please put <meta charset="utf-8"> in head section and see, it must fix it

Comment: I already put that in the DOCTYPE but still !

Comment: Is your code supposed to handle ANY sort of encoding, or only specific encodings?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Detect the current encoding & then convert it to `UTF-8`

```
$enc = mb_detect_encoding($text, "auto");
echo iconv($enc, "UTF-8", $text);
```